# import data into matlab from .cnv file

Tags: matlab, import

I am attempting to read some data from a .cnv file. I can open the file with:

```
TopFolder = 'Name_of_my_file';
SubFolder = dir(fullfile(TopFolder,'*.cnv'));
fid = fopen(fullfile(TopFolder,SubFolder{i}));
```

All of the data is located following the string END, which is on a separate line to the other headers. I would like to import the data that is stored on the lines following this string. How can this be achieved?

For example, the a section of the .cnv file is as follows:

```
# datcnv_in = D:\data\110606_000.hex D:\instrument software\Seabird 2010-07\Seabird Con Files\SBE19_2108_ScufaTOBS.con
# datcnv_skipover = 0
# file_type = ascii
*END*
     -0.051     0.0312    15.4328   138.1551     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000  0.000e+00
     -0.033     0.0305    15.4277   138.1551     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000  0.000e+00
```

So, I would like to avoid those lines prior to *End*

Maybe a first step would be to find the line number of END? How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all open the file and search through the lines until you find '*END*'

```
fid = fopen('yourfile.cnv')     % open file to read
fseek(fid,0,-1);                % set read position to beginning of file
while strcmp(fgetl(fid),'*END*') == 0 end        % go through lines until '*END*'
```

Next read data, line by line, into a matrix (`data`):

```
n=1;                            
while 1
    tline = fgetl(fid)                 % read in line
    if ~ischar(tline), break, end       % if eof, break and finish
    data(:,n) = sscanf(tline,'%f')     % put numbers in a matrix (in columns)
    n=n+1
end

fclose(fid)    % close file
```

Comment: Could you please explain how the first part of the script works. Although this works perfectly I don't understand how! If Linechk is intially equal to 0 how can it be equal to 1 after the while loop?

Comment: Also, what is the use of 'Linechk'? It is not used in the remainder of the code?

Comment: The Linechk variable is not necessarily required. I thought it made it easier to follow the code. It is essentially a flag that == 1 if the '*END*' sequence is found. I've updated the answer to remove the variable.

Answer (score 0):

When using the import wizard in matlab you can specify the number of header rows.
If you set this to four, it should work in this example.

After using the import wizard you can let it generate code if you want to automate the process for the future.

Comment: It would be good to be able to do this without having to specify the number of header rows i.e. being able to achieve this by specifying that the data begins on the line following the string END.

Comment: I guess there would be a more refined way, but a solution could be:
import the entire file as text, find the END, cut of the top, convert the rest of the file to numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
L = '';
while isempty(findstr(L,'*END*'))  % if the line doesn't contain *END* => read a new line
    L = fgetl(fid);                % read next line of file
end
a = fscanf(fid,'%g %g %g %g');     % add as many %g as columns in your data
fclose(fid);
```

I've added some comments on how this works. Basically, this reads the opened file line by line until it finds a line containing `*END*`.

You could use `strcmp(L,'*END*')` if there is more than 1 line that may contain the same characters.

A warning: this code assumes that the file you are reading contains at least one line that has the `*END*` characters, if not, you'll get an error when attempting to read beyond the EOF.

Hope this helps.